# How can I force update UI before program flow continues?

Tags: dm-script

For example, for the following code:

```
OpenOutputWindow()
Sleep(2)
```

The output window only opens AFTER sleeping for 2 seconds. Why does this happen and how does one work around it? Do I need multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is correct. UI updates of the software are generally performed on the "main thread" of the application. A script is, by default, also run on the main-thread and hence blocks those updates until some CPU cycles are made available for this.

Sometimes this can be achieved by calling dedicated *Update* commands (such as `UpdateImage()` or `ShowImage()` etc.) but this does not work for the text-output in the output window.

If the script is run on a separate thread, then you don't see this.
You can put a script into a separate thread like this (old method):

```
// $BACKGROUND$
OpenOutputWindow()
ClearResults()
Result("\nbefore sleep")
Sleep(2)
Result("\nafter sleep")
```

> Note that the first line needs to be *exactly* like this, including the space and capitalization. It also needs to be the first line.

or you can do it like that (new, object oriented way):

```
class CMyClass
{
    void MyMethod(object self)
    {
        OpenOutputWindow()
        ClearResults()
        Result("\nbefore sleep")
        Sleep(2)
        Result("\nafter sleep")
    }
}
StartThread( Alloc(CMyClass), "MyMethod" )
```